# Scrapy API - Pass custom logger

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

I am using the API to run Scrapy from a script (Python 3.5, Scrapy 1.5).

The main script calls a function to deal with its logging:

```
def main(target_year):
    project = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(os.path.abspath(__file__)))[0]
    iso_run_date = datetime.date.today().isoformat()
    logger = utils.get_logger(project, iso_run_date)

    scraping.run(project, iso_run_date, target_year)
```

Here is the function in the file "utils.py", with an additional class for formatting, that creates a logger with Python's logging library:

```
class UTCFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    converter = time.gmtime


def get_logger(project, iso_run_date):
    ip_address_param = 'ip'
    logger = logging.getLogger(project)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
        'log', '{}_{}.log'.format(project, iso_run_date))))
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = UTCFormatter(
        fmt=('[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03dZ] %({})s %(name)s %(levelname)s: '
             '%(message)s').format(ip_address_param),
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(
        logger, {ip_address_param: socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())})
    return logger
```

And here is the file "__init__.py" in Scrapy's directory:

```
@twisted.internet.defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl(crawler_process, project, iso_run_date, target_year):
    yield crawler_process.crawl(project, iso_run_date, target_year)


def run(project, iso_run_date, target_year):
    os.environ.setdefault(
        'SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'scraping.scraping.settings')
    crawler_process = scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess(
        scrapy.utils.project.get_project_settings())
    crawl(crawler_process, project, iso_run_date, target_year)
    crawler_process.start()
```

When I execute the script, I get logs from my main script in the output log file, but nothing from Scrapy.

When I add this inside my spider:

```
self.logger.debug('Test')
```

I get this error:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 980, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 830, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 570, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 539, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 383, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'ip'
Call stack:
  File "XXXXX.py", line 105, in <module>
    main(target_year)
  File "XXXXX.py", line 23, in main
    scraping.run(project, iso_run_date, target_year)
  File "/home/XYZ/virtualenvs/scraping/project/scraping/__init__.py", line 27, in run
    crawler_process.start()
  File "/home/XYZ/virtualenvs/scraping/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 291, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "/home/XYZ/virtualenvs/scraping/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1261, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/home/XYZ/virtualenvs/scraping/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1270, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
  File "/home/XYZ/virtualenvs/scraping/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 896, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/home/XYZ/virtualenvs/scraping/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/utils/reactor.py", line 41, in __call__
    return self._func(*self._a, **self._kw)
  File "/home/XYZ/virtualenvs/scraping/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "/home/XYZ/virtualenvs/scraping/project/scraping/scraping/spiders/XXXXX.py", line 47, in start_requests
    self.logger.debug('Test')
Message: 'Test'
Arguments: ()
```

Things were OK when I used basicConfig in my main script, it seemed Scrapy would just pick up this basic logger. But because of additional formatting, it looks like I need to use more advanced code for the logging.

I would like to be able to define a custom logger from my main script, as shown in the code, and have Scrapy use the same formatting with the same output file without having to redefine all of this a second time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that seems to work.

The main script is unchanged:

```
def main(target_year):
    project = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(os.path.abspath(__file__)))[0]
    iso_run_date = datetime.date.today().isoformat()
    logger = utils.get_logger(project, iso_run_date)
```

The file "utils.py" now only uses logging.basicConfig(), like I was doing before.

```
def get_logger(project, iso_run_date):
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename=os.path.abspath(os.path.join('log', '{0}_{1}.log'.format(project, iso_run_date))),
        format='[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03dZ] {0} %(name)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'.format(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())),
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
        level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime
    return logging.getLogger(project)
```

The file "__init__.py" is also unchanged:

```
@twisted.internet.defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl(crawler_process, project, iso_run_date, target_year):
    yield crawler_process.crawl(project, iso_run_date, target_year)


def run(project, iso_run_date, target_year):
    os.environ.setdefault(
        'SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'scraping.scraping.settings')
    crawler_process = scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess(
        scrapy.utils.project.get_project_settings())
    crawl(crawler_process, project, iso_run_date, target_year)
    crawler_process.start()
```

Now, all logging messages are output with the same custom format into the same log file. Also:

- Logs from the main script use the variable "project" as a name.
- Logs from the spider use the spider name as a name.
- Logs from Scrapy components use Scrapy components a names.